# How to find list of View(s) that has a specific Tag (attribute)

Tags: android, android-layout

I set tag for UI widgets and I want to retrieve a list of View that has a specific tag. Using `View.findViewWithTag("test_tag")` just return one View not all view that support tag.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: waqas i have a similar question . can you tell me what to do? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061833/androidone-button-id-for-many-buttons-on-expandable-list-children

Comment: See: http://android-wtf.com/2013/06/how-to-easily-traverse-any-view-hierarchy-in-android/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldnt expect an array of views from this method, since the method signature itself tells that it will return a single view.

```
public final View findViewWithTag (Object tag)
```

However, what you may do is to get your layout as `ViewGroup` and then iterate through all the child views to find out your desired view by doing a look-up on their tag. For example:

```
/**
 * Get all the views which matches the given Tag recursively
 * @param root parent view. for e.g. Layouts
 * @param tag tag to look for
 * @return List of views
 */
public static List<View> findViewWithTagRecursively(ViewGroup root, Object tag){
    List<View> allViews = new ArrayList<View>();

    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0; i<childCount; i++){
        final View childView = root.getChildAt(i);

        if(childView instanceof ViewGroup){
          allViews.addAll(findViewWithTagRecursively((ViewGroup)childView, tag));
        }
        else{
            final Object tagView = childView.getTag();
            if(tagView != null && tagView.equals(tag))
                allViews.add(childView);
        }
    }

    return allViews;
}
```

Comment: I know that method return just a View. I'm looking for a simple way to get all views. I think iterating through a ViewGroup isn't optimized solution.

Comment: how do you know that its not an optimized solution?

Comment: I don't know exactly, optimized is relative thing, so if no better solution found, it can be optimized.

I knew this way but i don't want to use it for some reason. but finally if no better solution found I will accept your answer.

Comment: also recursive method needed, i write it own but for better answer please provide that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int tags = 6; 
    for (int index = 0; index < tags; index++) {
        try{
            TextView txtView = (TextView)getView().getRootView().findViewWithTag("txtTag-"+index);
            txtView.setText(" TWitter/ @MOIALRESHOUDI ");
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple in my use case. For example there are twelve imageviews with a same tag in a layoyut.
When findViewWithTag("image") calls on. It will simply give first index single imageview in from a layout. The solution is simple when you got a imageview with that tag, simply set that imageview tag to empty string. Next time in iteration when findViewWithTag("image") calls on. It will simply give you the next imageview.

```
for(int inf = 0; inf < albumPageImagesInfoList.get(cardPosition); inf++){
            ImageView imageView = inflateView.findViewWithTag("image");
            if(imageView!=null){
                imageView.setId(uivid);
                imageView.setTag("");
                imgIndexId++;
            }
        }
```