# Android : how to get Views by TAGs?

Tags: android, layout, tags, view, identifier

I've created many Buttons dynamically with Tags identifiers, but I don't know how to find them by  tags, I've tried **findViewWithTag** but it doesn't work. 
If someone can show me how to do it by Identifiers or by Tags ? 
Can someone help me and give me an example how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my source code :

```
 public void onClick(View v) {



    if (v == buttonPlanificationRdvMed) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nbH; i++) {

                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    //tr.setOrientation(tr.HORIZONTAL);
                    TextView text_view = new TextView(this);
                    Button b =  new Button(this);

                    text_view.setWidth(1000);// give how much you need
                    j = j + averageConsultationTime;
                    HMA = ((BeganConsultationH * 60) + (BeganConsultationM))
                            + j - averageConsultationTime;

                    int h = HMA / 60;
                    int m = HMA % 60;
                    b.setBackgroundColor(0xff99cc00);
                    b.setText(h + "H" + nbH);
                    tr.addView(b);

                    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                        Button but = new Button(this);
                        but.setTag(table[k]+"_"+h + "H" + nbH);
                        but.setText(but.getTag()+""+table[k]);



                        tr.addView(but);

                    }
                    TL.addView(tr);

                }
```

Comment: `findViewWithTag` works as expected, why wouldnt it?

Comment: I've tried : Button btn = (Button)findViewWithTag   but i don't find this method ??? i just find GetViewById

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920559/how-to-find-list-of-views-that-has-a-specific-tag-attribute) from @waqaslam

Comment: see View#findViewWithTag